# What does $f(v)d^3v$ mean?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, notation, calculus

I am reading the derivation of Langmuir's Evaporation Equation. The author writes:

> That cylinder contains a volume $dA(vdt)cosθ$ and contains vapor molecules of the designated speed in the density **$f(v)d^3v$**. The product of multiplying those two numbers together tells us how many vapor molecules strike the given area of the interface in the given elapse of time.

$f(v)$ refers to the Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution Function.  For more context visit thiss webpage: http://bado-shanai.net/Map%20of%20Physics/mopLangmuirEvaporation.htm

Comment: Are you familiar with calculus? Infinitesimal quantities?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with Calculus.

Comment: Then, do you understand my explanation?

Comment: If you could somehow draw it, I'd be able to digest what you've written in your answer.

Comment: I am confused what exactly your problem is here

Comment: $d^3v=4\pi v^2 dv$ which is a spherical shell. From reading your answer  I imagine $d^3v$ as made up of small cubes.

Comment: It is not important how you split your space. Yes, in the case of Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution it makes sense to use spherical shells, but this is because $f$ does not depend on the velocity direction, only it's magnitude. You could do it either way, only the pieces need to be small. It is similar to a coordinate transformation under the integral — it does not change the result

Comment: Is there any place where I can read more about this? These ideas are very new to me. Thank you for the prompt replies.

Comment: Any book on thermodynamics covers this.

Comment: Under what topic?

Comment: Look for "Kinetic theory of gases". The Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution will be there as well

Comment: I found a book, I'll read this topic. Thank you once again.

Comment: You are welcome. If you don't mind, accept the answer so other people will know this question is resolved and it won't hung like thousands of others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This combination represents the following. $f$ in your reference is the number of particles per cubic  space volume per cubic velocity volume. When you multiply it by some volume in velocity space, you obtain the regular density — number of particles per volume. But, as $f$ itself depends on velocity, to obtain the total density of all particles with all velocities, you need to sum over infinitely many small volumes to obtain an accurate result — i.e., integrate.

$d^3 v$ is the notation from calculus that represents some very small cube of velocities with coordinates $(\vec{v}, \vec{v}+d\vec{v})$. $dv$ is just a small increment of velocity

---

Another way to look at $f$:

$f(\vec{v},\vec{x})$ is a number of particles with velocities in range $(v_i, v_i+dv_i)$ with coordinates in $(x_i, x_i+dx_i)$, where $dv_i$ and $dx_i$ are sufficiently small compared to the system you consider. If you want to know, how many particles with arbitrary velocities you have at some point (actually, small region of space around it), you need to sum over $v$:

$$ n(\vec{x}) = \Sigma_\vec{v} f(\vec{v}, \vec{x}) \cdot dV_\vec{v} $$

where $dV_\vec{v}$ is exactly your "discretization volume" — $d^3 v$.

If you are not familiar with calculus, this is a way to understand the above. But it will be hard to perform any actual calculation.

Comment: How do you imagine  this setup?

Comment: Shrey, could you please be more specific about what you don't understand, especially about Andrii's answer? One may divide the 3D space to a grid with lots of tiny cubes of volume $dv_x\,dv_y\,dv_z$. One cube has the tiny volume $d^3v = dv_x\,dv_y\,dv_z$. The integration is a summation over the cubes, in the limit where they are infinitely small.  $f(v) d^3 v$ is just a contribution to an integral - the product of the volume of a tiny cube and a number $f(v)$ that's basically constant in that small cube

Comment: @LubošMotl here it is important that integration is done over velocities, I tried to emphasize that

Comment: I fixed the comment before I could. All of this *is* happening in the velocity 3D space. But the mathematics of $d^3 v$ in this space is completely analogous to the mathematics of $dV = d^3 r$ in the 3D position space.

Comment: @ShreyAryan I added some more